# Comma separator in javascript/typescript/angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

"Hey guys ! I have a question about how can I format some numbers . For example I want the number 33304 to be converted as 333,04 and the number 108100 as 1081,00. The rule is to remain two decimals after comma separator. I tried with javascript format functions but I could not find the right solution. 
Can you help me with an answer pls?

Comment: Can you please show us the code what you have tried so far?

Comment: In angular you can use Custom Pipes for transforming value in this format.

Comment: I tried with split method and with toFixed() method from javascript . I am on the road and I can't show my code.   It's more of a problem of inserting a certain element(",") at a position with the rule of remaining 2 characters at the end .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using just JavaScript or TypeScript, you can write:

```
function format(n) {
  (n / 100).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
}
```

Examples:

```
num(33304) === '333,04';
num(108100) === '1081,00';
num(101) === '1,01';
num(50) === '0,50';
num(1) === '0,01';
num(0) === '0,00';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use number formatting method:

```
function formatNumber(num) {
      return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
    }

    console.info(formatNumber(2665)) // 2,665
    console.info(formatNumber(102665)) // 102,665
    console.info(formatNumber(111102665)) // 111,102,665
```

**source**:

https://blog.abelotech.com/posts/number-currency-formatting-javascript/

or

use the following one:

```
var str="33304";

var resStr=str.substring(0,str.length-2)+","+str.substring(str.length-2);

console.log(resStr);
```

Comment: he want  "," before last two digit.

Comment: you are right @SunnyGoel but i thought he can get a idea from there.

Answer (score 0):

Using Custom Pipes you can achieve this transformation. see the below example :-

```
//Component 

import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  'selector' : 'app-sample' ,
   template : '  <p>  Number   {{sampleValue | convertPipe}} '
})

export class SampleComponent{
  public sampleValue = 33300;

}

// custom Pipe

 import {Pipe} from '@angular/core'; 

 @Pipe(
   {name: 'convertPipe'}
   )
 export class ConvertPipe{
   transform(value: number){
       let temp1 , temp2 , returnValue;
       temp1 = value/100;
       temp2 = value%100;

       if(temp2 != 0){
          returnValue = temp1 + ',' +temp2;
       } else{
             returnValue = temp1 + ',00';
        }
     return returnValue;    
   }
  }
```

Hope it will help.